# Has Cosmos Db support for Multipolygons?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

The documentations says that Cosmos supports Multipolygons but when I want to query using it I don't get the expected result. 
If I change the multipolygon to a polygon the query works as expected.

This is the result of  ***ST_ISVALIDDETAILED*** with the multipolygon

> Invalid position. A position must be represented by an array of
>   numbers. There must be at least two elements in the array.

This is proof that the multipolygon is not working.
Has anyone been able to work with multipolygons?

**Note**:
I have used the multipolygon as example in the documentation.
I have created the spatial index for the property.

> {
>               "path": "/Region/Area/?",
>               "types": [
>                   "Point",
>                   "LineString",
>                   "Polygon",
>                   "MultiPolygon"
>               ]
>           }

Comment: can you share the query and the coordinates you are trying to retrieve?

Comment: I found the issue with the format of the Multipolygon

Answer (score 3):

After investigating more I found that the example on documentation is bad formed.
This is the example =>

```
{
    "type":"MultiPolygon",
    "coordinates":[ [
        [52.0, 12.0],
        [53.0, 12.0],
        [53.0, 13.0],
        [52.0, 13.0],
        [52.0, 12.0]
    ],
    [
        [50.0, 0.0],
        [51.0, 0.0],
        [51.0, 5.0],
        [50.0, 5.0],
        [50.0, 0.0]
    ] ]
}
```

and is invalid.

This is the right geoJson =>

```
{
    "type":"MultiPolygon",
    "coordinates":[ [[
        [52.0, 12.0],
        [53.0, 12.0],
        [53.0, 13.0],
        [52.0, 13.0],
        [52.0, 12.0]
    ]],
    [[
        [50.0, 0.0],
        [51.0, 0.0],
        [51.0, 5.0],
        [50.0, 5.0],
        [50.0, 0.0]
    ]]]
}
```